Как изменить параметры класса из другого проекта в Java?
Я создаю платформер, который находится в одном проекте(все классы находятся в пакете gameclasses). Я хочу создать второй проект(например чит), который увеличивает поле bounce из класса Player в проекте платформера. Код программы main во втором проекте:
   class BounceCheat
   {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
       gameclasses.Player.bounce = 30;
     }
   }

Сначала я добавил проект платформера в Search Dependendency in Maven Repository но когда я компилировал код выше, выдавалась ошибка, типа пакет gameclasses не существует.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка.

DavidJava, добавьте пожалуйста ваш код в вопрос, чтоб наглядно было

@Dev18, спасибо!
